# remove only duplicates ids

Tags: mysql

I got 2 tables: `job` and `job_working_time`

```
job: id (Increment, Index, Unique)
job_working_time: job_id(allow multiple), property_working_time
```

This SQL query returns the ids with multiple values or duplicates. It helps, but it doesn't fix my problem:

```
SELECT a.id AS id, count( b.job_id ) AS cnt, b.property_working_time AS value
FROM job a
INNER JOIN job_working_time b ON a.id = b.job_id
GROUP BY b.job_id
HAVING cnt >1
```

I want to remove duplicates, only for ids with duplicates, e.g: l = leave, r = remove

- 1 - 1 (l)
- 1 - 1 (r)
- 1 - 2 (l)
- 1 - 3 (l)
- 1 - 1 (r)
- 2 - 1 (l)
- 2 - 1 (r)
- 2 - 2 (l)

Thanks in advance

[Later edit]
One thing you should consider: 
Anyway, when I want to delete the ID, will remove all values for it. So, the idea is to keep all the values for that id, so later I can add without duplicates. That's why it's so important to retrieve, both the id and the value, but not duplicate content. The SQL should return all the (l) values from the above e.g. list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your example looks like you don't want any row be same

`DISTINCT` will work for you

it select completely diffirent rows

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id AS id, count( b.job_id ) AS cnt, b.property_working_time AS value
FROM job a
INNER JOIN job_working_time b ON a.id = b.job_id
GROUP BY b.job_id
HAVING cnt >1
```

**Edit:**

Example added

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/119267/

Comment: We don't want to lose different values for the same id, only duplicates values. Select should return all values for the ids, but not duplicates values.

Comment: you wont lose any full diffirent row with distinct, it checks "is full row same" if any of column diffirent, selects it

Comment: have you tried your SQL? I don't want to be rude, thanks for your interest, but DISTINCT won't help in my case.

Comment: @danielpopa ok then, give some example data and **exact** example result

Comment: check the list from example. lines marked with L, should remain in db.

Comment: @danielpopa with that example distinct perfectly works let me help you with an example database

Comment: sorry, I didn't mention that CREATE it's not an option because it's not allowed for me. let's say this topic it's closed. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @danielpopa `CREATE` is for creating temporary table since its an example database i cant create a static database just tempory one instead of your static, you just need to run `SELECT` query. If you give ur database schema i can write a query which will work without editing, this topic is closed because you are not helping.

Answer (score 0):

First/ simple Query:

```
SELECT id, field, count(*) c from ... group by  field having c >1
```

Second Query, modifed for get IDs to delete:

```
SELECT  instr(s,mid(s,',')+1) from (
SELECT group_concat(id) s, count(*) c from ... group by  field having c >1)z
```

and  the end:

```
Delete FROM ... WHERE id in ( ...)
```

looks ugly, but fast (Mid function performance is faster than not in (...)).

Comment: in case of 2 different values for the same id, your solution will loose first value (check later edit for more explanations)